# invoking an action helper

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a directory structure such that I have three directories inside my root directory, namely application, public and library.

Now, inside the library directory, I made a directory `Custom`, inside which I have a directory `Controller`, inside which I have a directory `Action`, inside which I have a directory `Helper`, and this directory contains a php file named '`LinkTo.php`'. Inside this file, I have a class named `Custom_Controller_Action_Helper_LinkTo` which extends `Zend_controller_Action_Helper` and provides with a simple function called `linkTo($inputString)`..which outputs the url as per the input string parameter. But, I get this error `"Action Helper by name CustomControllerActionHelperLinkTo not found "` even  though I have mentioned '`Custom_`' in autoload namespaces in my `application.ini`, and have also taken care of include paths in my `index.php`.

Please help! How does one make an action helper like that and invoke it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you specify path for the custom Action Helpers ?

You can do this in your `application.ini`, add following line:

```
resources.frontController.actionHelperPaths.Custom_Controller_Action_Helper_ = "Custom/Controller/Action/Helper"
```

After you specified path for your custom helpers, you need to initialize them for the later use. This can be done in `Bootstrap`:

```
protected function _initHelpers()
{
    Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper(new Custom_Controller_Action_H‌​elper_LinkTo());
}
```

If you want to use helper as a method of the helper broker, for instance:
`$this->_helper->LinkTo();` your custom helper should implement `direct()` method.

Comment: i added that to my application.ini, now when i use Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('Custom_Controller_Action_Helper_LinkTo'), and then invoke the helper using $resetFormLink = $lh->linkTo('/resetpassword/form'), I again get that same error...what is the correct way to invoke it?

Comment: I've added some explanation